# Is it possible for other half-elves (besides Earendil, Elwing and their descendants) to be presented with the choice of immortality?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, elves, edain

I know that through Earendil's line that exception was granted to him and his family. However, I wonder if it is possible for some of the other half-elves to be presented with that similar option.

Whilst through Imrazor and Mithrellas, their son Galador died as a mortal, nothing is known of Gilimith, their daughter.

Surely there must have been other examples or a slight possibility for other cases.

Comment: Great question! But I think you'll find that [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76358/31394) already covers the theory of Half-Elven mortality choices - who gets the choice, who doesn't, and why.